# Ceiling fan capacitor needed

Tags: ceiling-fan

I'm also looking for the control pull chain switch to control the 3 speed fan. Can anyone anyone help, seems the description for most switches out there don't give enough detail.

I found this  info in another question on this site. It's the same Hampton Bay ceiling fan I own.

I need a new capacitor. Do I need one with exactly the same specs? I find ones with out the matching voltage.

Here is what I have, though I can't confirm the CBB61 series, that was in post I am using as reference.

```
fan: Hampton Bay EF200D
CBB61 series capacitor, 4 wires:
    black: common
    blue: 3µF, 350V
    red: 3.5µF, 200V
    yellow: 6µF, 200V
3-speed, 4-wire pull-chain switch with terminals L, 1, 2, 3
```

The capacitor has component # E175257

Can anyone recommend a capacitor that will work?

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: You can find it on ebay, amazon, ect

Comment: Not the exact specs: 3uf 350v, 3.5uf 200v, 6uf 200v 4 wire capacitor.

Comment: ignore the voltage, it is only for maximum indication, you will newer exceed 120 Volt